# Call the findUniqueDigits function by passing secret as the argument and store the return list.(Say secretUniDigits)

Tags: python, list, function, return, call

could someone please help me understand what this line is trying to get me to do? Thanks.

findCows function: Write a function called “findCows” that takes two string values as parameters (Say secret, guess) and returns the number of digits in guess match the secret only in digit but not in position. Assume that there are exactly 4 digits in each string. For example, findCows(“1807”, “7810”) will return 3.

Comment: findCows function: Write a function called “findCows” that takes two string values as
parameters (Say secret, guess) and returns the number of digits in guess match the
secret only in digit but not in position. Assume that there are exactly 4 digits in each
string.
For example, findCows(“1807”, “7810”) will return 3.

Comment: Comments are not meant to be long-standing.  Make your question complete by [edit]ing it to include that.

Answer (score 1):

```
def findCows(secret, guess):
  sum([x!=y for (x, y) in zip(secret, guess)])
```

`zip(secret, guess)` converts two lists of the same size to a list of element-wise pairs. The `[x!=y for (x, y) in zip(secret, guess)]` statement is a `for` comprehension which maps each pair to `True`/`False` based on their equality. Finally, `sum` counts the number of `True` values.

Comment: your function is wrong, it will return the number of different elements and this is not what the op asked for.

Comment: @nino_705 Misread the original question, the answer is fixed. In any case, the difference is trivial as far as implementation.

Comment: Your code is giving the intersection of tow sets, if you read the  poster's comment on the question you will notice that he asks for common elements that are in wrong positions

Comment: Yup, I know, the answer has already been updated....

Comment: now it's a clever answer ;)

Comment: As clever as it is, it still returns `None` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter function:

```
len(list(filter( lambda x: x[0]!= x[1], zip(secret ,guess))))
```

Comment: You can actually omit the `list` typecast as `filter` already returns that type.

Comment: filter returns a `filter` object that doesn't support the `len` function

Comment: You're right, I was using Python 2.x. It looks like it's a `filter` object for Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter.